# Is it true $(X_n, Y_n) \rightarrow N( (\mu_1, \mu_2), diag(\sigma^2_1, \sigma^2_2))$ when $X_n$, $Y_n$ each goes to normal independently.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I have $X_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(\mu_1, \sigma^2_1)$, and $Y_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(\mu_2, \sigma^2_2)$, and $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

(Note that it does not imply $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent where $i \neq j$)

Can we say as follows, $(X_n, Y_n) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N_2\left((\mu_1, \mu_2), \begin{bmatrix} \sigma^2_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma^2_2 \end{bmatrix}\right)$?

My intuition is strongly positive about this, but I need a proof for this.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that characteristic functions will do the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(U,V)\sim N((\mu_1,\mu_2),\operatorname{diag}(\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2))$.  We claim $(X_n,Y_n)\xrightarrow{d}(U,V)$.
Indeed, by Levy's theorem it suffices to check characteristic function
$$
\begin{align*}
\varphi_{(X_n,Y_n)}(s,t)&=
\mathbb{E}[e^{i(s,t)\cdot(X_n,Y_n)}]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[e^{isX_n}]\mathbb{E}[e^{itY_n}]\\
&\to\mathbb{E}[e^{isU}]\mathbb{E}[e^{itV}]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[e^{i(s,t)\cdot(U,V)}]\\
&=\varphi_{(U,V)}(s,t)
\end{align*}
$$